# Animated Marker on Mapbox

Tags: ios, animation, mapbox

It seems that mapbox updated its ios SDK recently with some huge change.

For example, it seems that it is not possible anymore to provide a layer as a custom marker, or to animate a marker as in this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy/examples/cakeyframeanimation/

It seems that every reference to that example is related to a RMM* named class which has been deprecated.

How can I implement an animation in a Mapbox's MGLMapView?

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated, from a series of png to a CAEmitterLayer, to a generic view to be used as a marker so that I could do anything I want with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View-based annotations/markers is a feature that will be coming in the v3.3.0 release. Once you’re able to use views, you’ll also be able to use the same Core Animation methods you’re familiar with.

If you would like to try out a pre-release version of v3.3.0, have a look at [alpha 3](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases/tag/ios-v3.3.0-alpha.3), which has preliminary support for view-based annotations — see [`MGLAnnotationView`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/25c4436d37d84cb8eb800385b412e784a0789087/platform/ios/src/MGLAnnotationView.h).

Comment: I've tried also a basic .animatedImage approach, but the image isn't animated anyway                           ```let u:UIImage? = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("Ball-", duration: 1.0)
        ```

Comment: `MGLPointAnnotation` is takes an image and renders it as a static GL texture, which works well for volume but not dynamism. It has an `image` property that you _could_ update/animate, but it would not be performant.